# IsObject() error while iterating json array

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

I have the following code:

```
#include "E:\Harbinson\Desktop\VS Test\include\rapidjson\document.h"
#include "E:\Harbinson\Desktop\VS Test\include\rapidjson\writer.h"
#include "E:\Harbinson\Desktop\VS Test\include\rapidjson\stringbuffer.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace rapidjson;

int main()
{
    const char json[] = "{\"prog\":[{\"iUniqueID\":1,\"bGroup\":1,\"inFiles\":[{\"sFileType\":\"Zonal Data 1\",\"bScenarioSpecific\":0,\"pos\":{\"x1\":1555,\"y1\":-375,\"x2\":1879,\"y2\":-432}},{\"sFileType\":\"Record File\",\"bScenarioSpecific\":0,\"pos\":{\"x1\":1555,\"y1\":-436,\"x2\":1879,\"y2\":-493}}],\"outFiles\":[{\"sFileType\":\"Record File 1\",\"bScenarioSpecific\":1,\"pos\":{\"x1\":2344,\"y1\":-405,\"x2\":2662,\"y2\":-462}}]},{\"iUniqueID\":2,\"bGroup\":1,\"inFiles\":[{\"sFileType\":\"Matrix File 1\",\"bScenarioSpecific\":0,\"pos\":{\"x1\":98,\"y1\":-726,\"x2\":422,\"y2\":-783}},{\"sFileType\":\"Matrix File 2\",\"bScenarioSpecific\":0,\"pos\":{\"x1\":98,\"y1\":-787,\"x2\":422,\"y2\":-844}}],\"outFiles\":[{\"sFileType\":\"Record File 1\",\"bScenarioSpecific\":1,\"pos\":{\"x1\":887,\"y1\":-966,\"x2\":1205,\"y2\":-1023}}]}]}";

    Document d;
    d.Parse(json);

    const Value& prog = d["prog"];
    for (Value::ConstValueIterator p = prog.Begin(); p != prog.End(); ++p) {
        std::cout << (*p)["iUniqueID"].GetInt();
        const Value& inFiles = (*p)["inFiles"];
        for (Value::ConstValueIterator inFile = inFiles.Begin(); inFile != prog.End(); ++inFile) {
            std::cout << (*inFile)["sFileType"].GetString() << std::endl;
            std::cout << (*inFile)["pos"]["x1"].GetInt() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Compiles correctly, but when I run the executable I getting the following output and error:

> Assertion failed!
>
> Program: E:\Harbinson\Desktop\VS Test\Json2a\car.exe File:
> E:\Harbinson\Desktop\VS Test\include\rapidjson\document.h, Line 1335
>
> Expression: IsObject()

Answer (score 0):

You have a (copy+paste) error in your inner `for` loop

```
for (Value::ConstValueIterator inFile = inFiles.Begin(); inFile != prog.End(); ++inFile)
                                                                   ^^^^
```

should be

```
for (Value::ConstValueIterator inFile = inFiles.Begin(); inFile != inFiles.End(); ++inFile)
                                                                   ^^^^^^^
```